# Run custom code on startup of a Remix web application

Tags: remix.run

In a Remix Web application, how can we run custom code on startup?

For example, I want to initialize a database connection pool and run a dummy query to check for problems after the application starts. I know I could do that the first time I use the database, but that's not exactly what I want.

I'm using *Remix App Server* as deployment target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which adapter are you using? If you use Express, you can add your startup code to server.js. You can even pass objects (like connection pool) to Remix using the `getLoadContext` function.

https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#loader-context

Comment: I choose *Remix App Server* when creating the project with `create-remix`. Does it mean I'm using express under the hood? Besides, what do you mean by `server.js`, do I need to create such file?

Comment: Never mind. I just noticed that *Express* is one of the deployment targets and when you select it there is a `server.js` that initialize the whole app. Thanks @Kiliman.